# reactjs: no key assigned warning, but only for the first iteration

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 components:

```
Main
  -- adItem
     -- Offerslist
        --- offers (just li's, not a comp)

 //On the main comp containing state I add the offer and I pass the function down as a prop:

  _addOffer: function(offerData) {
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

    // add offer to item
    this.state.advitems[offerData.itemId].offers['offer-id' + timestamp] = offerData;
    this.setState({
      advitems: this.state.advitems
    });   
  },


/* 
  AdItem  
*/

var AdItem = React.createClass({
  _addOffer: function(event) { 
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    var offerData = {
      offerId: 'offer-' + timestamp,
      itemId: this.props.index,
      price: this.refs.offerprice.value
    };
  },
  render : function() {
       //some code to hide and show with css classes
       {renderOffers}
     )
    }
});

var Offerslist = React.createClass({
  _renderOffers: function(key) {
    var details = this.props[key];
    return (
      <li className="offer-of-item">
        &euro; {details.price}
        <a className="remove-offer" onClick={this._removeOffer}>X</a>
      </li>
    )
  },
  render : function() {
    return (
      <ol className="list-of-offers-per-item">
        {Object.keys(this.props).map(this._renderOffers)}
      </ol>
    )
  }
});
```

AdItem can contain multiple offers. When I enter the first offer, I get the warning that it should contain a unique key. I checked and it DOES have a unique key. When adding the second, I don't get the warning. But I'm unsure whether it just stops warning me or it's corrected in some way.

[image: image showing offers with key]

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm unsure of what to check next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate an array and create elements dynamically, you also have to add a `key` prop to said elements:

```
{Object.keys(this.props).map(this._renderOffers)}
```

`this._renderOffers` must return elements with keys that are unique relative to each other. The shortcut is to simply use the index in the array, but a much better approach that ensures that React knows how to properly tell one element from another is to use the offer item's id, if you know that it's unique:

```
_renderOffers: function(key) {
  var details = this.props[key];
  return (
    /* Add a key prop here. E.g. details.itemId */
    <li key={details.itemId} className="offer-of-item">
      &euro; {details.price}
      <a className="remove-offer" onClick={this._removeOffer}>X</a>
    </li>
  )
},
```

This makes sure that when you add or remove items, or alter the data, React only manipulates the corresponding DOM element, instead of redrawing the entire list, or potentially alter the wrong element.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
But if I use the item ID, I will have multiple offers using the same item ID, right? so shouldn't it be <li key={key}> in this case? I'm gonna try it!

Comment: @flowen Yeah, if you have multiple offers for the same item that would be correct. I don't really know what your data structure looks like, but just choose something that is unique in the context, and is consistent between each re-render.

Comment: great, thanks for the answer! I'll mark it, because it lead me to the solution.